# How can I configure Ubuntu/GNOME to accomodate my keyboard/mouse habits from Windows?

Tags: gnome, windows, keyboard, mouse

I've primarily used Windows, but recently switched to Ubuntu/GNOME at work.

In my Windows setup, the context menu is triggered on the *release* of the right mouse button; in my Ubuntu/GNOME setup, it's triggered on the *press*. This is causing me pain because apparently I've developed a habit in Windows of right clicking a bit early, i.e. while still moving the cursor. This has no undesirable side effect in Windows, but in my Ubuntu/GNOME setup, the click immediately brings up the context menu, and the residual movement can sometimes highlight a menu item, and the button release will then act on that selection.

In other words, in Ubuntu/GNOME, where as my intention is just to bring the context menu, I instead accidentally selected some menu item (usually the top most) and execute it. How can I prevent this from happening? Can I make Ubuntu/GNOME bring the context menu on *release* of right mouse button, the way I'm used to in Windows?

---

Another habit I've picked up is that I use Alt-F,S to save documents. Now, some editors (e.g. Eclipse) are "smart" in that it knows if a file doesn't need saving, and will disable the Save menu item in that case. Regardless, Alt-F,S would "work" in that it's a no-op (just like Ctrl-S would be). That is, even though Save is disabled, hitting S would still close the File menu, it just wouldn't save the document.

However, in Ubuntu/GNOME, when the Save menu item is disabled in Eclipse, Alt-F,S would get "stuck" on the File menu. Since Save is disabled, S would just not do anything, and the File menu stays open.

I know I can just try to switch to Ctrl-S instead, but can I just configure Ubuntu/GNOME to let me try Alt-F,S even if that particular menu item is disabled? (just ignore the action, just like Windows does).

---

By the way, I'm open to using another window manager if necessary.

Comment: Eclipse isn't a Gtk/GNOME application, and it seems like GNOME applications like `gedit` don't have this issue, so maybe this is more like an issue with Eclipse instead?

Comment: BTW: unlearning habits is often the most difficult part of moving to another platform...  ;)

Comment: This seems like it should be two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

The first question involves code changes to gnome, as far as I know there is no way to change this behaviour without code changes. you might want to report a bug.

The second question is a problem with Eclipse/Java.

Answer (score 0):

try kde, is more windows-like, gnome is more mac-like